# Mysql next prev row with ordering

Tags: mysql, database

I have tables

```
pages_id  aliases_name          pages_name                                 
--------  --------------------  ------------------
  88      main                  Главная                             
  90      novyny                Новости                             
  91      usluhy                Главная                             
  92      pomoshch              Помощь                               
  93      contact               Контакты                           
  94      dobavyt_nedvyzhymost  Главная                             
 132      zabyly_parol          Главная                              
 133      registration          Регистрация                     
 134      vashy_dannye          Ваши данные                      
 135      vashy_obiavlenyia     Ваши объявления              
 136      aktyvatsyia           Активация                         
 137      pravyla_y_uslovyia    Правила и условия           
 138      smena_parolia         Смена пароля                    
 140      about                 о нас
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `a_pages_pages` (
  `pages_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aliases_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pages_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pages_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=157 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Data in the table:

```
insert into `a_pages_pages` (`pages_id`, `aliases_name`, `pages_name`)  
values('88','main','Главная'), ('90','novyny','Новости'),  
      ('91','usluhy','Главная'), ('92','pomoshch','Помощь'),  
      ('93','contact','Контакты'), ('94','dobavyt_nedvyzhymost','Главная'),  
      ('132','zabyly_parol','Главная'), ('133','registration','Регистрация'),  
      ('134','vashy_dannye','Ваши данные'),
      ('135','vashy_obiavlenyia','Ваши объявления'),  
      ('136','aktyvatsyia','Активация'),  
      ('137','pravyla_y_uslovyia','Правила и условия'),
      ('138','smena_parolia','Смена пароля'), ('140','about','о нас')
```

I get simple query ...

```
SELECT pages_id, aliases_name, pages_name
FROM a_pages_pages
ORDER BY pages_name ASC
```

And when I know some ID (current row) from this query :

```
pages_id  aliases_name          pages_name                                 
--------  --------------------  ------------------
 136      aktyvatsyia           Активация                         
 134      vashy_dannye          Ваши данные                      
 135      vashy_obiavlenyia     Ваши объявления              
  91      usluhy                Главная                       
 132      zabyly_parol          Главная               <<<< prev row
  88      main                  Главная               <<<< current row
  94      dobavyt_nedvyzhymost  Главная               <<< next row
  93      contact               Контакты                           
  90      novyny                Новости                             
 140      about                 о нас                                  
  92      pomoshch              Помощь                               
 137      pravyla_y_uslovyia    Правила и условия           
 133      registration          Регистрация                     
 138      smena_parolia         Смена пароля
```

**I need get ID prev row and ID next row from this query.....**

---

What I know on that moment
`ORDER BY` - what columns and what ordering I have.. Order by can be w
`pages_id` - going from php.

PS. Use some scripts

---

Next:

```
SELECT pages_id, aliases_name, pages_name
FROM a_pages_pages
WHERE pages_name > 'Главная'
ORDER BY pages_name ASC, pages_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Not working because when I have `pages_id` = 132,88,94, then `next_id` = 132 all times

And with positions

```
SELECT * 
(SELECT 
    `pages_id` AS `id`, @pos := @pos + 1 AS `position` 
FROM
    `a_pages_pages`, 
    (SELECT 
        @pos := 0) AS `p_table` 
ORDER BY `pages_name` ASC) 
WHERE `position` >
```

??? I dont know POSITION

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will give you the next and previous page id by passing the current page id also in cycle that is if pageid is first then it will give you the last page id as previous in below query i have used page id 88 ,and used the  page_id column for order by so its easy to get the order

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT 
      pages_id 
    FROM
      a_pages_pages 
    WHERE pages_id < 88 
    ORDER BY pages_id DESC 
    LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT 
      MAX(pages_id) 
    FROM
      a_pages_pages)
  ) AS `prev`,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT 
      pages_id 
    FROM
      a_pages_pages 
    WHERE pages_id > 88 
    ORDER BY pages_id 
    LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT 
      MIN(pages_id) 
    FROM
      a_pages_pages)
  ) AS `next`
```

Sample output

```
PREV   NEXT
140    90
```

### [See fiddle  Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/629d0/1)

Comment: @CHORTik then explain your self and show the desired results you want from query

Comment: You are use only orderyng by Id. I need ordering by one of three column. As example I show ordering table on pages_name column where we having 4 simple rows... problem here what I cant get wright ID 132 and 94 as prev and next row...